# Pound sign encoding - not working in outlook for iOS

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP to write and send an HTML email. I need to display the pound sterling  sign in my mail body.

At the top of my php file i have the following line:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

At the beginning of my HTML output (between the  and  tags) I have the line:

```
$html .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
```

Then later in my html I have:

```
$html .= '<td rowspan="2" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:20px;">&pound; ' . $price . '</td>';
```

When I run my code and send an email, if I view it in outlook on my windows desktop then I see a £ sign. But when I view the email in outlook for iOS on my iPhone I see an i with two dots, an upside down question mark and a '1/2' sign.

I've tried using &#163 in place of &pound with the same result. I've also tried using the actual '£' sign in place of &pound. This doesn't work either but the email displays A£ instead of the 'I, upsidedown ?, 1/2' combo.

I know it's something to do with encoding but am stumped. When I open the file in notepad++ it says 'UTF-8' in the bottom right corner so where am I going wrong?

Comment: i have no real answer but how about wring an email in outlook with a pound, send it to your self, then view the email source to see what it uses,

Comment: Something between using `&pound;` and the final display in the email client is converting that entity into various wrong character sets and then doing even worse wrong character set conversions. Make sure that you're setting the correct character set in whatever library you're using to actually send the email, because that needs to be in the email's headers, not just the HTML part of the email body.